# Facing the NameError when trying to include concerns in my rails 6 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a small project for practising the API Key Authentication using the [this](https://keygen.sh/blog/how-to-implement-api-key-authentication-in-rails-without-devise/) tutorial. I have created a concern in following directory of the rails project.

**app/controllers/concerns/api_key_authenticable.rb**

```
module ApiKeyAuthenticatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  attr_reader :current_api_key
  attr_reader :current_bearer

  # Use this to raise an error and automatically respond with a 401 HTTP status
  # code when API key authentication fails
  def authenticate_with_api_key!
    @current_bearer = authenticate_or_request_with_http_token &method(:authenticator)
  end

  # Use this for optional API key authentication
  def authenticate_with_api_key
    @current_bearer = authenticate_with_http_token &method(:authenticator)
  end

  private

  attr_writer :current_api_key
  attr_writer :current_bearer

  def authenticator(http_token, options)
    @current_api_key = ApiKey.find_by token: http_token

    current_api_key&.bearer
  end
end
```

In my Controller, I am trying to include the concern like this

**app/controllers/ApiKeysController.rb**

```
class ApiKeysController < ApplicationController
  include ApiKeyAuthenticatable 
 
  # Require token authentication for index                             
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_with_api_key!, only: [:index] 
 
  # Optional token authentication for logout                           
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_with_api_key, only: [:destroy] 
 
  def index
  end
 
  def create
  end
 
  def destroy
  end
end
```

But when I run the server and visit the index action of the controller, I get the following error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ApiKeysController::ApiKeyAuthenticatable):
  
app/controllers/ApiKeysController.rb:10:in `<class:ApiKeysController>'
app/controllers/ApiKeysController.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Can anybody help me out to fix this issue?

Comment: Check the concern file name, it should be the same as the module being defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here. Your concern’s filename is `authenticable` but your module is `authenticatable`. You’ll need to correct the typo in the concern filename.